# Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.31.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies

Tags: c#, visual-studio, google-api, google-ads-api, google-api-dotnet-client

I am using Adwords API for developing excel add-in.
Before V201802 everything working fine. after release of Adwords API V201802 my application is not supporting properly. I am using Visual Studio 2015 for older Adwords Versions After releasing of V201802 its not supported I installed VS2017 and updated framework 4.5.2 because latest version of AdWOrds api is supported only 4.5.2.

**Could not create an instance of startup object project.ThisAddIn in assembly project, Version=3.5.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null.**

************** Exception Text **************

```
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Applications.Runtime.CannotCreateStartupObjectException: Could not create an instance of startup object project.ThisAddIn in assembly project, Version=3.5.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null. ---> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. ---> System.IO.FileLoadException: Could not load file or assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.31.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=4b01fa6e34db77ab' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
at project.ThisAddIn..ctor(ApplicationFactory factory, IServiceProvider serviceProvider)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at System.RuntimeMethodHandle.InvokeMethod(Object target, Object[] arguments, Signature sig, Boolean constructor)
at System.Reflection.RuntimeConstructorInfo.Invoke(BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.CreateEntryPoint(String entryPointTypeName)
--- End of inner exception stack trace ---
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.CreateEntryPoint(String entryPointTypeName)
at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.DomainCreator.ExecuteCustomization.Microsoft.VisualStudio.Tools.Office.Runtime.Interop.IExecuteCustomization2.LoadEntryPoints(IntPtr serviceProvider)
```

Comment: This may be a problem with the binding redirects in your project.

Comment: please could you explain briefly how can i solve my problem with binding redirect in my project.

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/configure-apps/redirect-assembly-versions Sorry, I don't know much about how to fix errors in these redirects; VS normally handles it all automatically. One thing that can help is to remove the dependencies, then re-add them; this might get VS to fix the problem.

Comment: I am getting warning like "Unable to find dependency 'GOOGLE.APIS' (Signature='4B01FA6E34DB77AB' Version='1.18.0.0') of assembly 'Google.Apis.Analytics.v3.dll' ". I downloaded the dll files from nuget package.